# Use of unresolved identifier 'numberBack'

Tags: swift

just started learning Swift 4 and it is confusing as hell.

so my code should return the reminder of the mod, and I have to figure out which one is greater first. Banging my head on the monitor for 3 hours already! and getting error "Use of unresolved identifier 'numberBack'"

```
func returnMod(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) -> Int {
    if numberOne >= numberTwo {
        let numberBack = numberOne % numberTwo
    } else {
        let numberBack = numberTwo % numberOne
    }
        return numberBack
    }
```

Comment: not familiar with swift, but i assume if creates its own context and let is basically context-wide. Define numberBack above your if-else statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a question about the scope of variables.

`let numberBack` is visible only between the braces. You are creating two different variables and return a third one which is not related to the others. That causes the error.

To get the variable in the same scope you have to write

```
func returnMod(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) -> Int {
    let numberBack : Int
    if numberOne >= numberTwo {
        numberBack = numberOne % numberTwo
    } else {
        numberBack = numberTwo % numberOne
    }
    return numberBack
}
```

or much simpler without the temporary variable

```
func returnMod(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) -> Int {
    if numberOne >= numberTwo {
        return numberOne % numberTwo
    } else {
        return numberTwo % numberOne
    }
}
```

Comment: even simpler `return numberOne >= numberTwo ? numberOne % numberTwo : numberTwo % numberOne`